# Transaction Backout with Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to backout a transaction with Oracle 12c with this script:

```
DECLARE
v_xid   SYS.xid_array;
BEGIN
v_xid := sys.xid_array ('0700200003030000');
DBMS_FLASHBACK.transaction_backout (numtxns => 1, xids => v_xid, options => 
DBMS_FLASHBACK.cascade);
END;
/
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-06550: Ligne 2, colonne 9 :
PLS-00201: l'identificateur 'SYS.XID_ARRAY' doit être déclaré
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting with `DBA` privileges? If not, are you sure that you have the necessary permissions to interact with `SYS` objects? As a regular user, you will not be able to interact with some `SYS` objects unless access has been explicitly granted to you. This is especially true if you are working within an organization's database, as it is a common occurrence for all grants to be revoked from the `PUBLIC` role.

If this is a case of permissions, there is not much you can do to fix it yourself. If you have access, you could try connecting with the `SYSDBA` role. If you do not have that access, you will need to request it from the `DBA` who manages the database.

If this is your database that you are using for testing/learning and you're not sure, I would recommend checking out Oracle's documentation on roles at the following link: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authorization.htm#DBSEG004

Here is also a great ask tom article that talks a little about the `SYS` schema and `SYSDBA` role.  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:2659418700346202574